# Unable to do manual MySQL install

Tags: mysql, installation

I tried following the instructions at below link, but I am sorry I am stuck:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-archive.html

I get this error when trying to run "mysqld --console":

```
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Binlog end
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-08-19 15:09:25 5404 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

"my.cnf" file is here. It is placed directly under the unzipped mysql folder.

```
[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir=C:/mysql
datadir=C:/mysql/data
#port=3306
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
#join_buffer_size = 128M
#sort_buffer_size = 2M
#read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Note: I can not download the Windows msi installer, so please don't mention that option.

Comment: Not a programming question. However this might help. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html mysqld --console --skip-innodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because default table engine is InnoDB but InnoDB support is disabled. You can try this - add line **default-storage-engine=myisam** under [mysqld] block in config file.

Edited for newest MySQL version:

```
[mysqld] 
innodb=OFF 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam 
default-tmp-storage-engine=myisam
```

Comment: thanks but now I get another error:2013-08-20 15:35:13 1104  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno:
 2
2013-08-20 15:35:13 6584 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-08-20 15:35:13 6584 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2013-08-20 15:35:13 6584 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-08-20 15:35:13 6584 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: What if you add another line in config file: skip-innodb ? Also make sure that Mysql data directory (C:/mysql/data) exists and is writable.

Comment: Tried skip-innodb (does not work). Error logs are written in C:/mysql/data, so it is writable. Anything else I can try? Why is this so tough?